# How transfer a string (not from form) from HTML page to the server?

Tags: django

I'm doing the task about creating web-project "library". When you are on the main page, you can see list of all the library users. If you press on any of the users' name, the another page with list of user's books will open. And this task became a problem for me: I don't know how server can get the string with user's name from the main page.

I thought about ajax, but I guess it works only for forms. And I don't want to turn my text list into form. It seems to be not optimal decision. Please tell me if there any any ways to do it?
I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: You put it in the URL. This is basic and is well covered in the tutorial.

Comment: It works! I didn't know about this possibility to put info in URL. It really looks very simple and beautiful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work.

html

```
<a href ="{% url 'wherever' query=namefromtextlist %}"> namefromtextlist would go here </a>
```

url

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('wherever/<query>', views.wherever, name='wherever')]
```

views

```
def wherever(request, query):
   ...
   return render(request, wherever.html)
```

Comment: Thanks for full answer and code example! I did it, and it works.

Comment: happy to help :)